# Streaming data from REST WCF service to an external web service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest

I'm trying to write a WCF web service that essentially boils down to a proxy for an external web service which is not in my control (specifically, a major video sharing site).  I need to be able to send ~10-100 MB of data from a client to my web service, and then send that data along to the external service.

I can do that, but to be able to scale, I'd like it to be streamed as much as possible, instead of reading the entire request body into memory and then POSTing it all in one chunk to the external service.

I have the `bindingConfiguration` set to `transferMode="Streamed"` in my config:

```
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WebHttpBindingConfig" maxReceivedMessageSize="104857600"
             transferMode="Streamed"
             maxBufferSize="104857600"
             maxBufferPoolSize="104857600">
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

The service takes a `Stream` as its only argument:

```
public abstract class Upload<NetworkID> : IUpload
{
    protected abstract string DatabaseConnection { get; }

    public Stream UploadVideo(Stream stream)
    {
        LogManager.GetLogger("Logger").Trace("Upload starting:");
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request;
            request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://faketestservice:8800/upload");
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

            request.ContentLength = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.ContentLength;
            stream.CopyTo(request.GetRequestStream(), 64 * 1024 * 1024);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogManager.GetLogger("Logger").Trace("caught: " + ex.ToString());
        }

        return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("hello upload"));
    }
}
```

The service simply takes the incoming request stream and copies it to the outgoing request stream, 64K at a time.

But when I try to send some data (~16MB in my example) to the service through Fiddler, monitoring what gets sent to the external service (in this example, a fake listener run on my home computer), none of the data is sent until all the data is received.

I've tried setting the `SendChunked` property on the outgoing request to true, but that doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a buffer size to be too large in the CopyTo function.  Set it to something small or leave it at default (4096) by not passing a buffer size at all.  You are basically telling it to transfer 64MB at a time.  That means it will read 64MB, send it, read 64MB more, send it, etc.

Additionally, you do not need to use 'Chunked' for this.  That is a special feature of HTTP that you do not require.

Beyond that, make sure Fiddler is not showing the response only after it has finished.  It might be lying to you.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you still have a single POST that reads the incoming stream and sends up to 64MB out.

What you (might) want to do is have your service loop through the incoming data, sending it (via individual POSTs) in small chunks to the final service, if the video sharing site can take data in parts? Which service is it?